# while loop returns a repeating random value rather than a new random value

Tags: java

I am currently just messing around with some code and I keep running into an issue. I want to create ten circles and simply have them bounce around the window. I've had a couple of problems (like when I want the circles to bounce off the wall, for some reason the 400,400 window isn't actually that size. I have the circles collide on the right by checking if `x + width >= 400`, but it bounces outside the screen unless I change the 400 to 380?), but my main issue is that when I create the circles, I want them to be in different locations (so they aren't colliding before they can even move). I am trying to get it so that if a circle is going to be 'inside' another circle then instead create random x and y coordinates again until it isn't inside another circle. But for some reason, if I put `r.nextInt()` inside the while loop it keeps giving me the same values. Can anyone help?
p.s. I wouldn't mind advice on any other mistakes I have made.

```
  package practicedots;

    import java.awt.Dimension;
    import java.awt.Graphics;
    import java.util.Random;
    import javax.swing.JFrame;
    import javax.swing.JPanel;

    public class PracticeDots extends JPanel {

        float dots[][] = new float[10][7];
        Random r = new Random();
        boolean first = true;

        float x = 0;
        float y = 0;
        float xAccel = 0;
        float yAccel = 0;
        int wall = 380;
        int width = 50;
        float radius = 0;

        float centreX = 0;
        float centreY = 0; 

        boolean collision;

        /**
         * @param args the command line arguments
         */
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            JFrame f = new JFrame();
            f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            f.add(new PracticeDots());
            f.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 400));
            f.setResizable(true);
            f.pack();
            f.setVisible(true);
        }

        /**
         *
         * @return
         */
        public float[][] CreateDots() {

            if (first == true) {
                for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                    while(collision == true){
                    x = r.nextInt(300);
                    y = r.nextInt(300);
                    xAccel = r.nextFloat() / 2;
                    yAccel = r.nextFloat() / 2;
                    radius = width/2;
                    centreX = x + radius;
                    centreY = y + radius;

                    dots[i][0] = x;
                    dots[i][1] = y;
                    dots[i][2] = xAccel;
                    dots[i][3] = yAccel;
                    dots[i][4] = radius;
                    dots[i][5] = centreX;
                    dots[i][6] = centreY; 
                    bounce();
                    }

                }
                first = false;
            } else if (first == false) {

                for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                    dots[i][0] = dots[i][0] + dots[i][2];
                    dots[i][1] = dots[i][1] + dots[i][3];

                    if (dots[i][0] >= wall - width) {
                        dots[i][2] = -dots[i][2];
                    }
                    if (dots[i][1] >= wall - 20 - width) {
                        dots[i][3] = -dots[i][3];
                    }

                    if (dots[i][0] < 0) {
                        dots[i][2] = -dots[i][2];
                    }
                    if (dots[i][1] < 0) {
                        dots[i][3] = -dots[i][3];
                    }     
                    bounce();
                }
            }

            repaint();

            return dots;
        }
    //(x2-x1)^2 + (y1-y2)^2 <= (r1+r2)^2
        public void bounce() {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                for (int a = 0; a < 10; a++) {
                    if (a != i) {
                        System.out.println((dots[i][0] - dots[a][0])*(dots[i][0] - dots[a][0]) + (dots[i][1] - dots[a][1])*(dots[i][1] - dots[a][1]) <= (dots[i][4] + dots[a][4]) * (dots[i][4] + dots[a][4]));
                        collision = (dots[i][0] - dots[a][0])*(dots[i][0] - dots[a][0]) + (dots[i][1] - dots[a][1])*(dots[i][1] - dots[a][1]) <= (dots[i][4] + dots[a][4]) * (dots[i][4] + dots[a][4]);
                    }
                }
            }

        }

        /**
         *
         * @param g
         */
        @Override
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);

            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                CreateDots();
                g.drawOval((int) dots[i][0], (int) dots[i][1], width, width);
                g.fillOval((int) dots[i][0], (int) dots[i][1], width, width);
            }
        }
    }


<!-- end snippet -->
```

Comment: Please don't post your whole code, post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: When you write, `if (first == true) `, it is more concise to write `if(first)` as it is already a boolean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were a couple of problems:

1. During `bounce` you should return the first time you find a collision, otherwise the collision will be set to true, but then could be set back to false on the next iteration in the for-loop.
2. In the `first == true` condition, you should initialize `collision` to `true` or it will never do the `while` loop at all. Either that or change it to a `do-while`.
3. During `paintComponent` you should not call `CreateDots` within the for-loop since it loops over all dots itself. Just call it before.

The code seems to work with these changes (including width of 400 not 380):

```java
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class PracticeDots extends JPanel {
    float dots[][] = new float[10][7];
    Random r = new Random();
    boolean first = true;

    float x = 0;
    float y = 0;
    float xAccel = 0;
    float yAccel = 0;
    int wall = 400;
    int width = 50;
    float radius = 0;

    float centreX = 0;
    float centreY = 0;

    boolean collision;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.add(new PracticeDots());
        f.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 400));
        f.setResizable(true);
        f.pack();
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    public float[][] CreateDots() {
        if (first == true) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                do {
                    x = r.nextInt(300);
                    y = r.nextInt(300);
                    xAccel = r.nextFloat() / 2;
                    yAccel = r.nextFloat() / 2;
                    radius = width / 2;
                    centreX = x + radius;
                    centreY = y + radius;

                    dots[i][0] = x;
                    dots[i][1] = y;
                    dots[i][2] = xAccel;
                    dots[i][3] = yAccel;
                    dots[i][4] = radius;
                    dots[i][5] = centreX;
                    dots[i][6] = centreY;
                    bounce();
                } while (collision == true);

            }
            first = false;
        } else {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                dots[i][0] = dots[i][0] + dots[i][2];
                dots[i][1] = dots[i][1] + dots[i][3];

                if (dots[i][0] >= wall - width) {
                    dots[i][2] = -dots[i][2];
                }
                if (dots[i][1] >= wall - 20 - width) {
                    dots[i][3] = -dots[i][3];
                }

                if (dots[i][0] < 0) {
                    dots[i][2] = -dots[i][2];
                }
                if (dots[i][1] < 0) {
                    dots[i][3] = -dots[i][3];
                }
                bounce();
            }
        }

        repaint();

        return dots;
    }

    public void bounce() {
        collision = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            for (int a = 0; a < 10; a++) {
                if (a != i && !(dots[a][0] == 0 && dots[a][1] == 0)) {
                    boolean thisCollision = (dots[i][0] - dots[a][0]) * (dots[i][0] - dots[a][0]) + (dots[i][1] - dots[a][1]) * (dots[i][1] - dots[a][1]) <= (dots[i][4] + dots[a][4]) * (dots[i][4] + dots[a][4]);
//                    System.out.println("collision: "+collision+" i="+i+" a="+a);
                    if (thisCollision) {
                        collision = true;
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        CreateDots();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            g.drawOval((int) dots[i][0], (int) dots[i][1], width, width);
            g.fillOval((int) dots[i][0], (int) dots[i][1], width, width);
        }
    }
}
```